# Using Unity, How should I Pass a "Model" to a Resolved Type?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I've got an interface, which we'll call `IFoo`, for argument's sake, that works with files. The implementation of this interface receives a `FileInfo` in its constructor. In my bootstrapper, I have it set up like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>();
```

The problem is that I don't know which `FileInfo` I need to pass into the `Foo` instance until it is resolved. I'll have one, and I need to pass it into the constructor.

I've seen older posts that recommend using a parameter override and the use of `container.Resolve`, but I understand that this is generally a bad practice.

Is there a recommended approach for achieving what I need to do?

TLDR: I need to be able to do something like this, that isn't frowned upon:

```
container.Resolve<IFoo>(*pass my constructor arg here*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I don't know which FileInfo I need to pass into the Foo instance until it is resolved.

This implies that `FileInfo` is *runtime data*, while your application components (your `Foo`) should not require *runtime data* during construction.

Please read [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) for a detailed discussion on why runtime data is bad, and which solutions there are.

Comment: I came to that conclusion myself. In thinking about how difficult it was getting to *construct* the object, I considered whether or not it was indicative of an underlying problem with the design of the class. I moved the argument from the constructor to a new method, and the problem handily resolved itself. Sage advice. Thank you.

Comment: Please be warned: If you moved the `FileInfo` to some sort of `IFoo.Initialize(FileInfo)` method, your component still requires runtime data during initialization, but now you introduced [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) as well.

Comment: The class in question provides file IO. It's a simplified deserializer with standard Open, Read, Close operations, and that's it. The amount of temporal coupling is, in my mind, acceptable. Avoiding temporal coupling is what led me to putting the `FileInfo` in the constructor in the first place, but in this *particular*, case temporal coupling is the lesser of two evils. (Bonus points for proper use of "temporal" in a sentence!!)